# IF -condition ERROR 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: mysql

How to fix ?

```
 mysql> SELECT  IF(1,(SELECT * FROM zd LIMIT 1 ) ,(SELECT *  FROM zd LIMIT 3) );
ERROR 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 1 column(s)
mysql>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error code is more informative than it may seem at first.

```
Operand should contain 1 columns
```

In your example, `IF` is the *operator*, while `1`, `(SELECT * FROM zd LIMIT 1 )`, and `(SELECT *  FROM zd LIMIT 3)` are the *operands*.

The IF statement takes three parameters: a boolean value, a *scalar* value to return if the boolean is true, and a scalar value to return if the boolean is false.

Your select subqueries each return a row. You must return only a single value, like this:

```
SELECT IF(1,(SELECT col1_name FROM zd LIMIT 1 ) ,(SELECT col2_name  FROM zd LIMIT 1) )
```

where you replace `col1_name` and `col2_name` with whichever columns you want to get data from.

====

Now that I read your question again, I see that what you're actually trying to do is conditionalize the limit. I would just do that in PHP or whatever language you're querying the database with, if that's possible:

```
$limit = $bool ? 1 : 3;
$mysql->prepare("SELECT * FROM zd LIMIT $limit");
$mysql->execute();
$result = $mysql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
```

I'm not sure there's a way to conditionally set the limit within mysql without variables.